# The size of the output layer does not match the number of classes in the classifier?

Tags: swift, xcode, keras, coreml, apple-vision

When I execute my computer vision app, it gives me the following error:

```
"The size of the output layer 'output1' in the neural network does not match the number of classes in the classifier."
```

My CNN has been trained on the chars74K dataset, and has been trained only on the 26 capital letters. I thought that meant that I had 26 classes in my network, and the output layer of my network therefore consists of 26 neurons with the softmax function. What am I doing wrong here? This is the rest of the text in the console:

```
2017-11-07 16:47:45.465734+0100 VisionApp[4472:347620] Error: The VNCoreMLTransform request failed
Error Domain=com.apple.vis Code=3 "The VNCoreMLTransform request failed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The VNCoreMLTransform request failed, NSUnderlyingError=0x60000064fe40 {Error Domain=com.apple.CoreML Code=0 "The size of the output layer 'output1' in the neural network does not match the number of classes in the classifier." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The size of the output layer 'output1' in the neural network does not match the number of classes in the classifier.}}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you converted the model using coremltools, the file with class names contains more or fewer than 26 labels.